# Why is this simple authentication not working

Tags: python, authentication

Ok, so I have this code that I have written:

```
Authorised = False
while not Authorised:
    useri = input("Enter your username: ")
    passi = input("Enter your password: ")
    users = open("Users.txt", "r")
    EndOfFile = False
    while not EndOfFile:
        userr = ""
        passr = ""
        line = users.readline()
        if line == "":
            EndOfFile = True
            continue
        splitlines = line.split(",")
        userr = splitlines[0]
        passr = splitlines[1]
        if useri == userr:
            if passi == passr:
                username = userr
                EndOfFile = True
                Authorised = True
                users.close()
            else:
                print("Wrong Password")
                EndOfFile = True
                users.close()
    if userr == "":
        print("Invalid username")
```

Users.txt:

```
A,B,
B,A,
```

For some reason when I run it it says that the password is wrong. I’m not sure why. If anybody could explain this to me it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue. It is working fine for me. Are you sure you are passing input in caps i.e `A` and `B`?

Comment: Yes, I have just inputted  `A` and `B`

Comment: `Enter your username: A`
`Enter your password: B`
`Wrong Password`
`Enter your username: `

Comment: can you share what your input and goal is? I can reproduce your error and I think I know whats not working, nothing is wrong I just don't think you wrote what you intended to

Comment: Ok, I dont know what was happening, I have re-written the txt and it works now. Strange :/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry haha I had already re written your code when I posted the comment, got up to get a coffee and got talking, but your going to get the post. Anyway, here's a few tips.

- You read the passwords in every loop, you don't need to do this.
- You can break your while loop much cleaner
- You have things that execute inside both the `if` and `else` sections of a selection, i.e.  `users.close()`
- In python it's easier to use a context manager to handle file i/o.

Take a look at something like this:

```py
with open('Users.txt', 'r') as pass_file:
    users = {}
    lines = [line.replace("\n", "") for line in pass_file.readlines()]
    for line in lines:
        split_line = line.split(',')
        users[split_line[0]] = split_line[1]

while True:
    useri = input("Enter your username: ")
    passi = input("Enter your password: ")
        
    if useri in users:
        if users[useri] == passi:
            print('Valid User')
            break
        else:
            print('Invadlid Login')
    else:
        print('Invalid Login')
```

This way you can build an initial `dict` objects with all your users and then just check that.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll try this :)

Answer (score 0):

Weird transferring error. I had Users.txt stored on onedrive, took it off onedrive, onto my iPad and was using Pythonista as the IDE. I’m not sure exactly what happened.